# Having a dispatchEvent triggered on an object how can I find out how to listen to it and where the event is dispatched?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, dispatchevent

I have some code build by someone else and I am trying to alter some form values when an event is dispatched

Here is the line of code

```
_instance.dispatchEvent ( "ADD_ROW",  { 'container' : $li, 'value' : data } );
```

What I can't seem to do on a global level is do something like this

```
someGlobalVariable.addEventListener('ADD_ROW', function (e) { console.log(11111); }, false);
```

or

```
document.querySelector('body #an_id').addEventListeneraddEventListener('ADD_ROW', function (e) { console.log(11111); }, false);
```

I don't know where the ADD_ROW is added or what global object I have to look at.

_instance looks like this on console.log

```
Object { _listenerMap: Object, indexOfListener: AbstractEventDispatcher/instance.indexOfListener(), addEventListener: AbstractEventDispatcher/instance.addEventListener(), removeEventListener: AbstractEventDispatcher/instance.removeEventListener(), hasEventListener: AbstractEventDispatcher/instance.hasEventListener(), dispatchEvent: AbstractEventDispatcher/instance.dispatchEvent(), release: AbstractEventDispatcher/instance.release(), rowCount: JSONFieldSetList/_instance.rowCount(), addRow: JSONFieldSetList/_instance.addRow(), deleteRow: JSONFieldSetList/_instance.deleteRow(), 4 more… }
```

Is there a way I can track what is happening and where the event is dispatched?

Answer (score 0):

This `_instance` object, is it part of some framework? or is it just some local variable somewhere and you don't know how it was created?

Regardless, if its dispatchEvent method behaves as defined in the [EventTarget interface](http://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#interface-eventtarget), then the object referenced by `_instance` is the target. An object doesn't need to be a node, or in the DOM, to be a valid event target, it only needs to implement EventTarget. For example, XHR objects and EventSource objects can listen to DOM events, yet those events will not traverse the HTML DOM to get there.

Can you not just add your listener to `_instance` or keep a global reference to `_instance`?

Comment: I think _instance is a local/temp value. I have a global object that might contain _instance but I am not sure how to access the event. see someGlobalVariable

Comment: OK. Do you know how to use event listeners? have you tried adding one to `_instance` directly as I suggested? if not, is there a reason you can't do it?

Comment: that is next on my list, hopefully I can trigger one on my html element and access it using simple jQuery or a plain js selector

Comment: I don't think so, still not sure how it was used. Maybe the event was applied on the local _instance with the hope that it will later be triggered from the main object.

Answer (score -2):

I manage to solve it by adding my own event.

```
$li.trigger('ADD_ROW');
```

+

```
$('body').on('ADD_ROW', '.multi-field-set-bottom-links.row.multi-field-set-row', function(){});
```

Thx

Comment: that doesn't actually answer your original question

Comment: I know but I think the event was not accessible globally from another file. I think _instance was a private of a global object and the event is only "harvested" locally. So I created my own event(same name) on the element that I wanted to target(not some parent). This question should be deleted as it doesn't help anyone but might give ideas to others on how to solve